# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined, Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to validate my checkboxes to make sure that the user checked at least one, however I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined.

Here is part of the HTML:

```
<form name="userSurvey" onsubmit="return validAll()" action="mailto:suvery@worldbook.com" method="post">
  Name (Required): <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" required=""><br> E-Mail (Required): <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" required=""><br> Phone (Required): <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required="" onchange="validNumber()"><br>
  <br>
  <p>Please choose your favourite types of books.(check all that apply)</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Science Fiction">Science Fiction
  <input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Travel Guide">Travel Guide
  <input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Short Story Collection">Short Story Collection
  <input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Other">Other <br>
  <textarea></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  <input type="reset" name="reset">
</form>
```

and part of the JavaScript for the checkboxes:

```
function validChoice() 
    {
        var bookChoice = document.userSurvey.books.value;
        var x= "";


        for (i=0;i< 4;i++)
        {
            if (document.userSurvey['bookChoice'+i].checked)
            {
                bookChoice = document.userSurvey['bookChoice'+i].value;
                x = x +"\n"+ bookChoice;        
            }
        }

        if (bookChoice == "")
        {
            window.alert("You must select at least one book category.");
                return false;
            }
        else
        {
            var userName = document.userSurvey.userName.value;
            var eMail = document.userSurvey.email.value;
            var phoneNo = document.userSurvey.phone.value;     
            return true;
    }
}
```

I am currently learning in JavaScript therefore I would prefer help in JavaScript only.

Full Code on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7qh5segc/

Comment: In which line? I can't see in your code that you get element before to check its checked or not.

Comment: @ColinCline in the first IF Statement below the Loop.

Comment: did you mean `document.userSurvey[bookChoice+i]` (without the quotes round bookChoice)? Otherwise it looks for a an element in the form which is literally called "bookChoice0", which doesn't exist. Whereas I think what you actually want is for it to use the value of the bookChoice variable? Still I think there are better ways to do this validation.

Comment: @ADyson I have added JSFiddle, maybe that would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You missed some tag names and missspell them in js function:

```
<h1>User Survey</h1>

<h2><strong>User Information</strong></h2>
<p>Please enter your details below</p>
<br>
<form name="userSurvey" onsubmit="return validAll()" action="mailto:suvery@worldbook.com" method="post">
Name (Required):
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" required="">
<br> E-Mail (Required):
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="">
<br> Phone (Required):
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required="" onchange="validNumber()">
<br>
<br>
<p>Please choose your favourite types of books.(check all that apply)</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Science Fiction">Science Fiction
<input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Travel Guide">Travel Guide
<input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Short Story Collection">Short Story Collection
<input type="checkbox" name="books" value="Other">Other
<br>
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset">

</form>
```

and js code goes like this:

```
function validName() {
  var name = document.userSurvey.userName.value;


  if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(name)) {
    alert("Please enter letters a - z only");
    document.userSurvey.userName.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }


}

function validNumber() {
  var theNumbersOnly = "";
  var theChar = "";
  var theInput = document.userSurvey.phone.value;

  for (i = 0; i < theInput.length; i++) {
    theChar = theInput.substring(i, i + 1);
    if (theChar >= "0" && theChar <= "9") {
      theNumbersOnly = "" + theNumbersOnly + theChar;
    }
  }

  if (theNumbersOnly.length < 10) {
    alert("You must enter 10 numbers.");
    document.userSurvey.phone.focus();
  } else {
    var areacode = theNumbersOnly.substring(0, 3);
    var exchange = theNumbersOnly.substring(3, 6);
    var extension = theNumbersOnly.substring(6, 10);
    var newNumber = "(" + areacode + ") ";
    newNumber += exchange + "-" + extension;

    document.userSurvey.phone.value = newNumber;
    return true;
  }
}



function validEmail() {
  var email = document.userSurvey.email.value;
  var atLoc = email.indexOf("@", 1);
  var dotLoc = email.indexOf(".", atLoc + 2);
  var len = email.length;


  if (atLoc > 0 && dotLoc > 0 && len > dotLoc + 2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Please enter your e-mail address properly.");
    return false;
  }
}



function validChoice() {
  //var bookChoice = document.userSurvey.books.value;
  var bookChoice;
  var x = "";


  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (document.userSurvey.books[i].checked) {
    console.log(document.userSurvey);
      bookChoice = document.userSurvey.books[i].value;
      x = x + "\n" + bookChoice;
    }
  }

  if (bookChoice == "") {
    window.alert("You must select at least one book category.");
    return false;
  } else {
    var userName = document.userSurvey.userName.value;
    var eMail = document.userSurvey.email.value;
    var phoneNo = document.userSurvey.phone.value;
    console.log(userName);
    console.log(eMail);
    console.log(phoneNo);
    return true;
  }
}




function validAll() {
  if ((validName() == true) && (validEmail() == true) && (validNumber() == true) && (validChoice() == true)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You missed email tag name too. regards

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the checkbox issue using the following code. A sensible way to get all the checkboxes in this case is using their shared "name" attribute. There are other ways if your structure was different - e.g. using a CSS class, or adding some other custom attribute to the elements.

```
function validChoice() {
  var bookChoices = "";

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("books"); //get all elements named "books" into an array

  for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) { //loop the array
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) { //if the array item at this index is checked, then add it to the list
      bookChoices += "\n" + checkboxes[i].value;
    }
  }

  if (bookChoices == "") {
    window.alert("You must select at least one book category.");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert(bookChoices); //just for testing
    return true;
  }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/7qh5segc/3/ for a demo using the changed validChoice() function.